# adding hyperlinks to indesign

Tags: xml, hyperlink, adobe-indesign

I'm fairly new to Adobe Indesign, but I'm ok with various coding languages.

I want to create a web-based document that lists some products and product descriptions with each product description acting as a hyperlink to the online product itself.

I have got as far as creating the XML that lists the various attributes I want to import via XML, but I'm having trouble with defining the URL to act as the hyperlink.

My current xml looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<list>

<product href="http://www.google.co.uk">
<BrandName>Brand 1</BrandName>
<Title>Shirt</Title>
<FullPrice>£25</FullPrice>
<ProductCode>ABC123</ProductCode>
</product>

<product href="http://www.google.co.uk">
<BrandName>Brand 2</BrandName>
<Title>Jacket</Title>
<FullPrice>£20</FullPrice>
<ProductCode>DEF456</ProductCode>
</product>

</list>
```

However, it just isn't working.
I'm probably missing something really simple, but I'm currently at a loss.

I just want to be able to drag elements from the structure onto my page, save as a PDF and know that each product will be linked through to the relevant hyperlink.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does each XML element represent in the InDesign document? (ie. textframe, paragraph, applied character style, etc.)

Comment: I am basically creating a catalogue of products in a 3x3 grid.
Each xml element relates to what I am wanting displayed on the page. E.g. I want for product '1' to display:

Brand 1
Shirt
£25
ABC123

But for all of that text in my text box to link to the url associated with it.

Comment: So, each `product` element is associated with a text box in InDesign, and each `BrandName`, `Title`, `FullPrice`, `ProductCode` element is associated with the text inside the text box?

Comment: yes. If you imagine that I just want all the elements 'within' the product to be listed as text, and then for all of those elements to be able to go to a hyperlink. I was hoping i'd just be able to add it to the xml as listed above, and frankly, i'm finding it a little odd as to why it's so difficult, but I guess it's meant for mainly print-based work, but I would have thought that what I want to do would be crucial to any e-book creators?!

Answer (score 3):

XML is disconnected from InDesign DOM objects. You have to explicitly define which XML element goes with which InDesign object, usually by tagging. By giving the `product` XML element an `href` attribute your not actually telling InDesign that it is a hyperlink.

In order to tell InDesign it *is* a hyperlink, you can loop through each `product` XML element using the InDesign javascript engine and apply the hyperlink to the text based on the element's attribute.

Here's an example:

```
#include "./XML Rules/glue code.jsx"

main();

function main() {
   var doc = app.activeDocument;
   var elems = doc.xmlElements;
   var ruleSet = new Array (new Rule);
   __processRuleSet(elems[0], ruleSet);

   function Rule() {
      this.name = "Rule";
      this.xpath = "//product[@href]";
      this.apply = function(elem, ruleProcessor) {
         var elemText = elem.texts[0];
         var linkURL = elem.xmlAttributes.itemByName("href").value;
         var linkSource = doc.hyperlinkTextSources.add(elemText);
         var linkDest = doc.hyperlinkURLDestinations.add(linkURL);
         doc.hyperlinks.add(linkSource, linkDest);
         return true;
      }
   }
}
```

There might be a simpler way, but I'm not aware of it.

Comment: Hi Josh, thank you for this post. Unfortunately my requirements have now changed. It seems I now need to link images rather than text. Do you know of a way of running a script to automatically hyperlink images with certain file names within the document?? 

I realise this is a complex request. If not, then thank you for the time you spent on my problem. Rachael

Comment: I'm sure it's possible, but I'll let that be something for you to figure out. I've provided a sample script, but it would be nice to see a little effort on your part into figuring out how to script this yourself. [This post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/150238/196793) explains my reasons a little bit for not solving this problem for you.

Comment: Late to the party but you can link image. Inline Images - <BannerImage href="FULL LOCAL PATH URL">